# Which yocto release tag to choose

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, release, yocto

We are planning to release our Embedded Linux product using Yocto.

Currently, I see 'Warrior' is the stable release version.

https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases

Looking at the poky source code, I find lot of tags.

https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/refs/tags

How to decide on choosing the tag. I see poky-yocto tag, poky-warrior tag

Comment: https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tag/?h=warrior-21.0.1 is the latest official stable release of Yocto based on *Thud*

Comment: Are not Thud and Warrior different? What do you mean by Thud?

Comment: sorry, you use top of Warrior as it has not had any releases

Comment: They are going by alphabet. Warrior is the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

Unless your hardware supplier provides you with a customized Yocto version (usually a Linux kernel, related patches and some recipes to setup specific hardware), you should always start with the latest stable version available at the moment, because it will contain the latest fixes from the community, and probably you are interested on them.